# Is this a good way to set more properties value after query?

Tags: c#, .net-core

This is what I do to set more properties value after query. Please see the method GetMoreData(), it will be executed for every detail loop and starts causing performance issue.

Is there a better way of doing this? I know the class constuctor that execute during object instantiate. But in this case, more properites must be set after database query.

Note: This is a cut-down version of source code focusing on important part only, please accept typo error, if any.

```
public class OrderHeader
{
    // Real database column
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public string ColA { get; set; }
    public string ColB { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalWeight { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalShipmentFee { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDetail
{
    // Real database column
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public string OrderLine { get; set; }
    public decimal Weight { get; set; }
    public decimal ShipmentFee { get; set; }

    // mock-up column for displaly only, not exist in datababse
    public string ColA { get; set; } 
    public string ColB { get; set; } 
}
 
public static List<OrderDetail> GetByItemClass(string itemClass) 
{
    using (IDbConnection db = new MySqlConnection(connectionStringGoesHere)) {

        string sqlCmd = @"SELECT * FROM orderdetail WHERE ItemClass = @ItemClass";

        List<OrderDetail> orderDetails = db.Query<OrderDetail>(sqlCmd, new {
            @ItemClass = itemClass
        }).ToList();
        
        // Get or build or calculate additional properties
        for (int i = 0; i < orderDetails.Count; i++) {
            orderDetails[i] = GetMoreData(orderDetails);
        }

        return orderDetails;

    }
}

public static List<OrderDetail> GetByItemType(string itemType) 
{
    using (IDbConnection db = new MySqlConnection(connectionStringGoesHere)) {

        string sqlCmd = @"SELECT * FROM orderdetail WHERE ItemType = @ItemType";

        List<OrderDetail> orderDetails = db.Query<OrderDetail>(sqlCmd, new {
            @ItemType = itemType
        }).ToList();
        
        // Get or build or calculate additional properties
        for (int i = 0; i < orderDetails.Count; i++) {
            orderDetails[i] = GetMoreData(orderDetails);
        }

        return orderDetails;

    }
}

public static OrderDetail GetMoreData(OrderDetail orderDetail)
{

    // Performance problem: Need to query order header for every
    // single loop even multiple records having the same OrderId
    OrderHeader orderHeader = OrderHeaderDal.GetById(orderDetail.OrderId);
    
    // Directly map value
    orderDetail.ColA = orderHeader.ColA;
    orderDetail.ColB = orderHeader.ColB;
    
    // Calculate value
    if (orderHeader.PostCode == "0") {
        orderDetail.ShipmentFee = orderDetail.Weight * 1.15;
        
    // More complex to get value from another table
    } else {
        
        // Might also cause performance issue for many query loop
        Rate rate = RateDal.GetByPostCode(orderHeader.PostCode);

        orderDetail.ShipmentFee = orderDetail.Weight * rate.RatePerKg;
    }

    return orderDetail;
}
```

Comment: Not enough details to be sure, but I suppose that you are hitting the database too often. Perhaps you can let dapper do the mapping of your properties givin a proper joined query between _orderdetails_ and _orderheader_

Comment: This is called an N+1 problem. You need to do either one big joined update and split it out with Dapper multi-mapping. Or do two queries in the same batch, one for the header and one for the detail, and split them out with `QueryMultiple`